# Words in string break in the middle, JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-hyphens

I'm currently trying to write hangman game in JS (i'm novice in WEB techs) and I've encountered my first obstacle. My placeholder string for the word to guess, that is a string of hyphens and spaces, breaks through the end of the div containing it.

*For example*

> If there is 7 dashes placeholder at the end of the line it
>   breaks into 6 dashes that stay at the top line and one dash which goes
>   to the bottom line.

It looks awful. How can I prevent this behavior and maintain my guess sentance as one string?

```js
var word = 'Some text you have to guess and which should not break in the middle of any word';

    word = word.toUpperCase();

    var word1 = '';
    var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') word1 += '-';
        else word1 += ' ';
    }

    function showHiddenWord() {
        document.getElementById('WordBox').innerHTML = word1;
    }

    showHiddenWord();

window.onload = start;

function start(){
    var div_content = '';
    
    for(i = 0; i < 35; i++)
    {
        var element = 'l'+i;
        div_content += '<div class="letter" onclick="check('+i+')" id="'+element+'">'+letters.charAt(i)+'</div>';
    }

    document.getElementById('alfabet').innerHTML = div_content;

    showHiddenWord();
}

String.prototype.Swappo = function(place, sign) {
    if (place > this.length - 1) return this.toString();
    else return this.substr(0, place) + sign + this.substr(place+1);
}

function check(nr) {
    var chosen = false;
    for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        if (word.charAt(i) == letters.charAt(nr)) {
            word1 = word1.Swappo(i,letters.charAt(nr));
            chosen = true;
        }    
    }
    if (chosen == true){
        var element = 'l'+nr;
        document.getElementById(element).style.background = "#003300";
        document.getElementById(element).style.color = "#00C000";
        document.getElementById(element).style.border = "3px solid #00C000";
        document.getElementById(element).style.cursor = "default";
        document.getElementById(element).style.boxShadow = "none";
        showHiddenWord();
    }
}
```

```css
#container
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 900px;
}

#WordBox
{
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#alfabet
{
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    min-height: 280px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
    grid-row-gap: .5em;
    grid-column-gap: .5em;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.letter
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 3px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="WordBox"></div>
    <div id="alfabet"></div>

</div>
```

Sorry if I miss any other necessary part of the code. I will gladly take any help since I can't find any via google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#WordBox` like this :

```js
var word = 'Some text you have to guess and which should not break in the middle of any word';

word = word.toUpperCase();

var word1 = '';
var lettersToSwap = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
{
    if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') word1 += '-';
    else word1 += ' ';
}

function showHiddenWord() {
    document.getElementById('WordBox').innerHTML = word1;
}

showHiddenWord();
```

```css
#container
{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 900px;
}

#WordBox
{
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  min-height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="WordBox"></div>
</div>
```

And if you want to keep line break and avoid dashed word to break you may consider wrapping them inside `span` and make them **inline-block** by updating your js like this :

```js
var word = 'Some text you have to guess and which should not break in the middle of any word';

word = word.toUpperCase();

var word1 = '';
var letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  if (word.charAt(i) != ' ') word1 += '-';
  else word1 += ' ';
}

function showHiddenWord() {
  var r = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < word1.length; i++) {
    if (word1.charAt(i) != ' ') r += word1.charAt(i);
    else r += '</span><span>';
  }
  r = "<span>" + r + "</span>";
  document.getElementById('WordBox').innerHTML = r;
}

showHiddenWord();

window.onload = start;

function start() {
  var div_content = '';

  for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    var element = 'l' + i;
    div_content += '<div class="letter" onclick="check(' + i + ')" id="' + element + '">' + letters.charAt(i) + '</div>';
  }

  document.getElementById('alfabet').innerHTML = div_content;

  showHiddenWord();
}

String.prototype.Swappo = function(place, sign) {
  if (place > this.length - 1) return this.toString();
  else return this.substr(0, place) + sign + this.substr(place + 1);
}

function check(nr) {
  var chosen = false;
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == letters.charAt(nr)) {
      word1 = word1.Swappo(i, letters.charAt(nr));
      chosen = true;
    }
  }
  if (chosen == true) {
    var element = 'l' + nr;
    document.getElementById(element).style.background = "#003300";
    document.getElementById(element).style.color = "#00C000";
    document.getElementById(element).style.border = "3px solid #00C000";
    document.getElementById(element).style.cursor = "default";
    document.getElementById(element).style.boxShadow = "none";
    showHiddenWord();
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

#WordBox {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#WordBox span {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#alfabet {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  min-height: 280px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-row-gap: .5em;
  grid-column-gap: .5em;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.letter {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="WordBox"></div>
  <div id="alfabet"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then it will run outside of my div and all I want is to simply move whole dashed word to the bottom line instead of just part of it.

Comment: @0x07 Ah ok, am gonna upadate my anwser !

Comment: @0x07 updated my answer, check it please ! i added a part for what you want

Comment: Your code is working as intended, thanks! BUT in my case it cant do the job because of the rest of my JS code (i've updated it in my question). The problem is I need to replace dashed in the var word with letters as the users will guess any. Check my update for details.

Comment: @0x07 you can still do this with my solution as i simply replaced spaces with `span` so the dashed are still present and you can modify them without problem, i don't think it will be an issue (i don't see your updates)

Comment: Sorry for the dealys but I have to translate var names from my main lang to eng so u don't get confused. And that causes a lot of problem when it comes to running the code ;).

Comment: @0x07 you still have issue, can you correct please and i will help you to update it with my solution

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I cant figure out what is the problem of not working code i rewrite here. It does work on my browser after running it from html file. I'm confused and I understand your patiance won't stay forever.

Comment: @0x07 you are missing some HTML,i don't see an element with id `alfabet`

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out after reading the whole code once again. Thanks.

Comment: @0x07 sorry it's a bit buggy, am gonna fix it ;)

Comment: @0x07 check again my answer, it should work fine and you will understand what i changed :)

Comment: I see only width property missing (am I blind?). And this is not the solution I'm looking for because there will be one more div containing graphic left to alfabet div and it both should be the same width (half of 900px). I didn't mention it, sorry for that.

Comment: @0x07 i simply removed  the width so we can see the result here as it's lower than 900px, but you can added it, it's only CSS. I only focused on the JS part and the `span` i added

Comment: Sir, you have my gratitude. Your solution fits my needs perfectly! I've tested it on others strings as well and it works as intended. Thanks for your engagement and for your patience! Edit: what is more, I can understand your code and what you have done so the knowledge will stay with me forever. Thanks once again.

Comment: @0x07 it was a pleasure and glad that you learned new things ;) you may also consider accepting the answer to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

use CSS `word-break`:

```
#WordBox {
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

keep-all Breaks are prohibited between pairs of letters.
CSS Syntax:

```
word-break: normal|break-all|keep-all|initial|inherit;
```

Please find the doc:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp